# Can't open phone application programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

```
 NSString *phoneStr = @"tel:";
 phoneStr = [phoneStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@" , self.ContactPhone];
 NSURL * phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneStr];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

This code does not working and not open phone application, and when I print the value of the phoneURL it is always null

why this is happens?

Thx

Comment: ContactPhone is of NSString type?

Comment: Firstly there is no need to type cast NSURL. Secondly, is there any value in phoneStr?

Comment: Yes, there is a value in the PhoneStr, and i print it and get the correct value

Comment: Can you log your `self.ContactPhone` and check

Comment: in any of the case if you have a value in ContactPhone, NSURL is getting properly initialized. with ur code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the phone string:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[phoneStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed **//** after **tel:**

```
NSString *phoneStr = @"tel://";
 phoneStr = [phoneStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@" , self.ContactPhone];
 NSURL * phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneStr];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
```

Comment: if i replace the value of the ContactPhone with static string it works fine, i.e like this 

 phoneStr = [phoneStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"55555"];

and i am sure that the contactPhone value is NOT null

Comment: Do one thing. Instead of self.ContactPhone just use ContactPhone. And are you sure ContactPhone is a NSString?

Comment: Yes I also remove self, and still phoneURL is null

Comment: Please write the value of phoneStr.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that self.ContactPhone is not empty and use ***@"telprompt://"*** to return back or relaunch of your app after ending call.

```
NSString *phoneStr = @"telprompt://";
if([self.ContactPhone length]>0)
{
phoneStr = [phoneStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@" , self.ContactPhone];
NSURL * phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneStr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And here the code for **Swift 4.1**

```
if let url = URL(string: "tel://" + phoneString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```